# How to change file versus folder indentation of the Explorer View in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I prevent Visual Studio Code from indenting the files differently then the directories?
The expand of a folder within a folder should be aligned with the files within the folder.
From my example below, it looks like the files are within the 'src' folder, when they are actually within the 'ClientApp' folder.

[Image showing that the files within 'ClientApp' do not align with the folders within 'ClientApp'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwbVF.png)

I looked through the visual studio settings and I did not find any settings for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's just like that. I'm not aware of there being a setting for this. I agree that it's visually confusing. As a workaround, you could increase the `workbench.tree.indent` setting's value to make it more apparent, or you could install a icon theme that [opts in to hide explorer arrows](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme#folder-icons-in-file-icon-themes).